# Assigning different entities to different prototype cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, entity, fetch

I'm making a coredata app on Xcode. I have several entities that all populate cells in their own tables using their own styles of prototype cells. I would like to view all entities on one master table, and send each entity to populate its matching cell.

I believe the best way to do this is to create an abstract entity and use if statements to declare cellidentifiers for each entity. I could be wrong, because it hasn't worked yet. Here's what I have:

In viewDidLoad:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                          entityForName:@"MyAbstractEntity" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[request setEntity:entityDescription];
```

The relationship is set up in the data model. Here's the table which tries to identify the sub-entity:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *identifier;

if ([NSEntityDescription entityForName:@“Animals” inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext])
{
    identifier = @“AnimalsCell";


    AnimalsCell *animalsView = (AnimalsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AnimalsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Animals *animals = (Animals *)[reportArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    animalsView.descriptionTextField.text = [animals description];
    return animalsView;
}

if ([NSEntityDescription entityForName:@“Plants” inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext])
{
    identifier = @“PlantsCell";


    PlantsCell *animalsView = (PlantsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



    Plants *plants = (Plants *)[reportArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    plantsView.flowerTextField.text = [plants flowerDetail];
    return plantsView;
}
return 0;
}
```

If I enter an animal, it shows up on the overview table. If I enter a plant, it crashes because it tries to put the plant data into an animal cell, which means my identifier if statement isn't working properly. This is my first time trying to display data from multiple entities and I've never used an abstract entity, so I could be doing it all wrong. Thanks a lot, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ([NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Animals" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext])
```

is *always true*, because the condition in the if-statement returns an entity description
and that is not `nil`. That code does not identify the entity of the current object
to be displayed.

What you can do is to compare the actual object's entity name:

```
MyAbstractEntity *object = [reportArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *entityName = object.entity.name;
if ([entityName isEqualToString:@"Animals"]) {
   Animals *animals = (Animals *)object;
   ...
} else if ([entityName isEqualToString:@"Plants"]) {
   Plants *plants = (Plants *)object;
   ...
} else {
   // What ???
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks you so, so much. This makes sense and solved my problem exactly in minutes.

Comment: @user3754137: You are welcome. - Just note that using an abstract parent entity has also disadvantages: Core Data then uses a *single* SQLite table for the parent entity and all its child entities. That needs more space and might be less efficient.